# Terribly slow boot on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: boot

I just moved on from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 17.04 Zesty Zapus one day ago. Everything is fine except the boot up time. In my Windows 10 my pc would take probably less than 10 secs to boot up. But in Ubuntu it is taking 2-3 mins to take me to the log in screen. I have run dmesg and it seems that something is getting wrong after 7 seconds. I'm attaching the result below. I also ran the boot process in cui mode and found that there was a hold for 1 min and 30 secs saying 'A start job is running for dev disc'. In other answers it has been provided that editing fstab file, checking for correct UUID will solve the matter but I have done with all this still the problem goes on.

I currently have one partition installed that is the entire disc (/dev/sda1). I did a clean install of ubuntu and erased the whole disc while installing. 
My configuration is 3 GHz intel Pentium dual core CPU, 4 GB RAM, 1 TB HDD with no other os installed except Ubuntu 17.04 with latest updates.
I hope anyone could solve this problem for me. Thank you very much.

[dmesg output](http://oikyo.do.am/dmseg.txt)

Comment: what does `systemd-analyze blame` say?

Comment: I went on a gui mode while bootup and found out there was a hold saying a sart job is running by dev mapper... and a start job is running by dev disc.. simultaneously, one for 1 min 30 sec and one for no limit. After 1 min 30 sec the boot process continued. I also chkecked the etc/fstab and saw there were swap partitions written but I actually don't have any seperate partitions for that so I removed them keeping only the partition ubuntu is using. I also ckecked UUID using lsblk -f and it was correct. Still the problem is going on.

Comment: I currently have only one partition (/dev/sda1) that is the entire disc because I had selected the erase entire disc while installing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Windows 8 is a lot faster than Ubuntu 13.10 on the same laptop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/430147/why-windows-8-is-a-lot-faster-than-ubuntu-13-10-on-the-same-laptop)

Comment: Anyways when I applied systemd-analyze blame it gave me this output : https://pastebin.com/n7DywTu9

Comment: Please post your UPDATE as an answer to the question, instead of adding it to the question

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept your answer. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! Send me a message in the comments if you want my up-vote. I'm taking the liberty to revert [your edit](/revisions/919950/4). :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem of slow booting. When I saw the boot messages it showed me that a startup process is running my dev mapper. I checked the `/etc/fstab` and there was a swapfile indicating `/swapfile` but I checked using `free -m` that I didn't have a swap set up. So I set up a swap but still the problem remained unchanged. The actual problem was that there was an unexisting drive listed on the `/etc/crypttab` which was causing the issue. I commented out the line and now it boots fine.

So if you have starup job slow boot issue, please do check:

1. Do you have a swap? Check it using `sudo swapon -s`
2. Check whether the swap is listed in fstab properly. Also check whether there are any other unexisted device listed. If there is, comment it out by putting `#` and a space at the starting of the line.
3. If step 1 and 2 fails or not relevant then check whether any unexisted device listed on `/etc/crypttab`. If there is, comment it out.