# Ubuntu 17.04 takes 3 minutes from GRUB to the login screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 17.04, hp, systemd

I’m Running Ubuntu Budgie 17.04 on a HP Envy 13 with 8 GB RAM, an SSD and a I5 core,so I expect Ubuntu to boot quickly.
I’m dual booting with Windows 10 and have disabled fast start up in windows settings. Secure boot is enabled.
I’ve seen a few “fixes” such as [Terribly slow boot on Ubuntu 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/919950/terribly-slow-boot-on-ubuntu-17-04)
but it will not let me save the edited file nor am I sure how much of the file to edit to try this.

Here’s the output of `systemd-analyze`:

```
jake@jake-HP-ENVY-13:~$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 3.046s (firmware) + 2.865s (loader) + 1.564s (kernel) + 3min 482ms (userspace) = 3min 7.958s

jake@jake-HP-ENVY-13:~$ systemd-analyze blame
          5.022s nmbd.service
          1.904s fwupd.service
          1.454s apparmor.service
          1.414s plymouth-read-write.service
           560ms dev-nvme0n1p5.device
           368ms NetworkManager-wait-online.service
           335ms systemd-resolved.service
           193ms postfix@-.service
           126ms lightdm.service
           124ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
           102ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
            98ms systemd-timesyncd.service
            95ms networking.service
            86ms keyboard-setup.service
            86ms ModemManager.service
            83ms smbd.service
            80ms snapd.service
            77ms upower.service
            74ms tlp.service
            68ms accounts-daemon.service
            68ms apport.service
            66ms NetworkManager.service
            57ms speech-dispatcher.service
            55ms irqbalance.service
            53ms gpu-manager.service
            53ms grub-common.service
            53ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
            50ms systemd-logind.service
            48ms systemd-journald.service
            47ms thermald.service
            46ms bluetooth.service
            41ms avahi-daemon.service
            33ms alsa-restore.service
            32ms systemd-udevd.service
            31ms udisks2.service
            26ms snap-repair.service
            26ms pppd-dns.service
            25ms colord.service
            25ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-FA26\x2d239C.service
            24ms packagekit.service
            23ms systemd-modules-load.service
            23ms plymouth-start.service
            20ms user@1000.service
            20ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
            18ms geoclue.service
            17ms polkit.service
            14ms ureadahead-stop.service
            14ms rsyslog.service
            12ms setvtrgb.service
            10ms resolvconf.service
          5.022s nmbd.service
          1.904s fwupd.service
          1.454s apparmor.service
          1.414s plymouth-read-write.service
           560ms dev-nvme0n1p5.device
           368ms NetworkManager-wait-online.service
           335ms systemd-resolved.service
           193ms postfix@-.service
           126ms lightdm.service
           124ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
           102ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
            98ms systemd-timesyncd.service
            95ms networking.service
            86ms keyboard-setup.service
            86ms ModemManager.service
            83ms smbd.service
            80ms snapd.service
            77ms upower.service
            74ms tlp.service
            68ms accounts-daemon.service
            68ms apport.service
            66ms NetworkManager.service
            57ms speech-dispatcher.service
            55ms irqbalance.service
            53ms gpu-manager.service
            53ms grub-common.service
            53ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
            50ms systemd-logind.service
            48ms systemd-journald.service
            47ms thermald.service
            46ms bluetooth.service
            41ms avahi-daemon.service
            33ms alsa-restore.service
            32ms systemd-udevd.service
            31ms udisks2.service
            26ms snap-repair.service
            26ms pppd-dns.service
            25ms colord.service
            25ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-FA26\x2d239C.service
            24ms packagekit.service
            23ms systemd-modules-load.service
            23ms plymouth-start.service
            20ms user@1000.service
            20ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
            18ms geoclue.service
            17ms polkit.service
            14ms ureadahead-stop.service
            14ms rsyslog.service
            12ms setvtrgb.service
            10ms resolvconf.service
            10ms wpa_supplicant.service
             9ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
             8ms systemd-remount-fs.service
             8ms dev-mqueue.mount
             7ms dev-hugepages.mount
             7ms snapd.autoimport.service
             6ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
             5ms systemd-journal-flush.service
             5ms ufw.service
             5ms boot-efi.mount
             4ms systemd-user-sessions.service
             4ms systemd-sysctl.service
             4ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
             4ms kmod-static-nodes.service
             3ms systemd-update-utmp.service
             3ms rtkit-daemon.service
             3ms systemd-random-seed.service
             2ms console-setup.service
             2ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
             2ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
             1ms swapfile.swap
           927us postfix.service
           385us snapd.socket
lines 51-73/73 (END)
```

What can I try/do to speed this up?
I'm a novice so ELI5 please.

Comment: This link provided me with a solution to the problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/905031/ubuntu-desktop-17-04-64-bit-with-encrypted-home-slow-boot

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be that the ubuntu is waiting for the swap partition to appear. Take a look at this:

[Ubuntu Desktop 17.04 64-bit with encrypted home, slow boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/905031/ubuntu-desktop-17-04-64-bit-with-encrypted-home-slow-boot)

In order to edit the files use

```
sudo gedit /etc/crypttab
```

and

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

Making use of sudo gives you the elevated privileges needed to edit these files.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the numbers for my machine and it boots like a rocket with 17.04 Ubuntu Mate, SSD and I7 kaby lake. You can compare them to yours for big differences.

The first thing I would do is be sure and display the boot process by following these directions:

> [How to enable boot messages to be printed on screen during boot up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25022/how-to-enable-boot-messages-to-be-printed-on-screen-during-boot-up)

Look to see where the delays are as it boots.

Mine takes 13 seconds to get to "booting in insecure mode" and 14 more seconds to ask me for my password.

```
sudo systemd-analyze blame
      8.840s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      4.030s fwupd.service
       550ms systemd-resolved.service
       512ms dev-sda3.device
       372ms click-system-hooks.service
       340ms winbind.service
       338ms vboxdrv.service
       279ms home-john-Libraries.mount
       239ms gpu-manager.service
       237ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       231ms swapfile.swap
       225ms user@1001.service
       207ms tlp.service
       192ms snapd.service
       188ms accounts-daemon.service
       157ms ModemManager.service
       117ms irqbalance.service
       114ms apport.service
       111ms thermald.service
        95ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-5649\x2dD6F4.service
        89ms grub-common.service
        88ms pppd-dns.service
        87ms keyboard-setup.service
        84ms alsa-restore.service
        84ms lm-sensors.service
        77ms NetworkManager.service
        72ms networking.service
        68ms extra.mount
        66ms upower.service
        57ms teamviewerd.service
        56ms apparmor.service
        56ms avahi-daemon.service
        49ms swapspace.service
        47ms repowerd.service
        41ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
        41ms systemd-udevd.service
        41ms speech-dispatcher.service
        40ms systemd-logind.service
        36ms udisks2.service
        35ms bluetooth.service
        33ms colord.service
        33ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
        32ms smbd.service
        29ms lightdm.service
        26ms polkit.service
        25ms systemd-sysctl.service
        22ms dev-mqueue.mount
        21ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
        21ms systemd-journald.service
        21ms systemd-modules-load.service
        19ms rsyslog.service
        19ms ufw.service
        18ms plymouth-read-write.service
        17ms kmod-static-nodes.service
        16ms binfmt-support.service
        15ms nmbd.service
        14ms systemd-update-utmp.service
        13ms ureadahead-stop.service
         9ms systemd-journal-flush.service
         7ms boot-efi.mount
         7ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
         6ms dev-hugepages.mount
         5ms resolvconf.service
         5ms dns-clean.service
         4ms systemd-user-sessions.service
         4ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         4ms snapd.autoimport.service
         3ms snapd.socket
         3ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
         3ms openvpn.service
         3ms vboxweb-service.service
         3ms vboxautostart-service.service
         3ms vboxballoonctrl-service.service
         3ms setvtrgb.service
         2ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
         2ms systemd-remount-fs.service
         2ms systemd-random-seed.service
         2ms rtkit-daemon.service
         1ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
         1ms console-setup.service
         1ms rc-local.service
       872us plymouth-quit-wait.service
```